# Flutter: sqflite sum amount is null in text widget

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

Disclaimer, I am quite new to coding in general, but I have tried researching for several days and also using the answers to several similar questions on here but none of them seem to be working. I appreciate your patience with a beginner.

I am using raw query in my database file as follows

```
 Future getTotal() async {
    var db = await this.database;
    var result =
        await db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(amount) as sum FROM $expensesTable");
    print(result.toString());
    return result;
  }
```

I am trying to display the sum of the "amount" column in my database in a text widget. Here is the code for that UI and text widget:

```
class BudgetAppState extends State<BudgetApp> {
  ExpensesDatabase databaseHelper;
  ExpensesDatabase expensesDatabase = ExpensesDatabase();
  List<Expenses> expensesList;
  double getTotal;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => false,
      child: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Budget App"),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        ),
        drawer: NavigationDrawer(),
        body: Text(getTotal.toString()),
      ),
    );
  }

  void displayTotal() async {
    var total = await databaseHelper.getTotal();
    setState(() {
      print('$total');
      getTotal = total;
    });
  }
}
```

The individual row data from the "amount" column in my database is showing up in a different List view widget I have on a different page in my app, but when I try to use this to SUM all the "amounts", the text for this is showing up as null. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're never actually initializing your `getTotal` property by calling your `displayTotal` method. When you're initializing the state of your widget make sure to call `displayTotal()`. Once it's done it will rebuild your widget and show you the value of `getTotal`.

```dart
class BudgetAppState extends State<BudgetApp> {
  ExpensesDatabase databaseHelper;
  ExpensesDatabase expensesDatabase = ExpensesDatabase();
  List<Expenses> expensesList;
  double getTotal;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    displayTotal();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => false,
      child: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Budget App"),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        ),
        drawer: NavigationDrawer(),
        body: Text(getTotal?.toString() ?? 'Loading...'),
      ),
    );
  }

  void displayTotal() async {
    var total = await databaseHelper.getTotal();
    setState(() {
      print('$total');
      getTotal = total;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Since your `databaseHelper` isn't initialized in this class either you're probably going to run into another `null exception` with the code I provided. If you're passing in the `databaseHelper` to your `StatefulWidget` make sure to use `widget.databaseHelper` to get access to it instead of reinitializing it inside of your `State` class.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `Text` widget should wait until your `async` gets executed.

If so, in this case, you can do something like this.

```
Text(getTotal.toString() ?? "Loading"),
```

which means when `getTotal` is `null`, it shows "Loading".

Hope that works!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is that my `getTotal`  is returning `null`, when I have several `amounts` in my database that it should be getting the SUM of, but it doesn't seem to be doing that.